# WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service Throwing Exception When Deployed On Server

Tags: wcf, windows-services, .net-4.5

I have a WCF Service library that I have hosted in a Windows Service. Both projects are using .NET Framework 4.5. I have copied WCF Service configuration into Windows Service “app.config”. For reference the config in windows service project looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>   <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />   </startup>   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SmartDataExchangerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=SmartDataExchanger; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   </connectionStrings>   <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's    app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SmartDataExchangerService.SchoolService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SmartDataExchangerService/SchoolService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SmartDataExchangerService.ISchoolService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="127.0.0.1" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="SmartDataExchangerService.UserService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SmartDataExchangerService/UserService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SmartDataExchangerService.IUserService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   </system.serviceModel> </configuration>
```

I am installing the service on development machine using following command:

1. “InstallUtil.exe” “C:\Test\MyServiceHost.exe”

The service is getting installed successfully. Also I am able to consume the WCF service on development machine. So everything working as expected on development machine.

Now I am trying to install this windows service on Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I am following these steps:

1. Copied “Dubug” folder content of Windows Service project from
   development machine onto server.
2. Opened a command prompt in administrator mode.
3. Run the command:

“InstallUtil.exe” “C:\Test\MyServiceHost.exe”

On execution above command returns following error:

> Exception occured while initializing the installation:
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid directory on URL..

I have so far made following attempts:

- Removed  element from config file as suggested in inline
  comment.
- Change the startup object to ServiceName.Program.
- Instead of using localhost, I tried using machine public IP
  Address.
- Checked my WCF Service is not using any file from local drive
  i.e. no use of “C:\” or “D:\”.

Can someone suggest any step I should try to solve this issue.

UPDATE:

The issue is solved. I restarted the PC, performed the steps a fresh and it got solved. I suspect I was not giving correct path while executing the command (silly me).

Comment: This is an error with the installation - it has nothing to do do with WCF.  Does the directory "Test" exist in the root of C:\ on the server?

Comment: @Tim - Thanks Tim for your comment. I restarted the PC, performed the steps a fresh and it got solved. I suspect as you correctly pointed out I was not giving correct path while executing the command.